# How to put a '+' sign inside a square like xor

Tags: math-operators

In $\oplus$, '+' sign is there inside a circle. I want to put similarly a '+' sing inside a square.
How is it possible in latex?

Comment: Maybe `$\boxplus$`?

Comment: @Jairo A. del Rio: Thanks a lot.